# flash as3 - generating a random number within a certain range, based on cursor position

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an object which I want to rotate between -45 and 45 degrees, but I want that to be based on the mouse position. If the mouse position is at zero, I want the object to be at -45 degrees. If the mouse position is at the stageWidth, I want the object to be at 45 degrees. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the "random" bit of your title, which seems not to apply to the actual question:

```
var angle:Number = (e.stageX*90/stage.stageWidth) - 45;
```

If you want to limit it, you can use min and max:

```
angle=Math.max(angle,-45);
angle=Math.min(angle,45);
```

or conditionals like this:

```
if (angle<-45) angle = -45
else if (angle>45) angle = 45;
```

or you can restrict the x value to the range (0 to stageWidth) before doing the translation.

Comment: Just to add some clarification to his correct answer - "e" is the MouseEvent when you set a MOUSE_MOVE listener, so e.stageX is a property of the event. You could also use mouseX to get the mouse coordinates, either way works fine.

Comment: @jhocking - Thanks, yes I did assume this would be inside a MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE event handler function. mouseX would be the same as stageX if this listener is attached to the stage or to a clip with the same coordinate space as the stage, otherwise you may need a localToGlobal() call to get your point in stage coordinate space first.